# Java and JNI - Loading dll libraries only works on my computer

Tags: java, dll, load, java-native-interface

I'm facing some annoying problems to get my java application working with external c++ dlls, through JNI. The libraries are located inside packages. I copy them to a temporary folder when I need to load them into virtual machine. The dlls are the next:

libcurld.dll;
libfftw3f-3.dll;
libmad.dll;
libsamplerate.dll;
main.dll;

The main.dll is the one that implements the native method declared on the java side. This dll depends on the above to run properly. I only compiled the main.ddl on visual studio, one binary for 7 other for xp. The others were downloaded and simply linked. I run the next method to load the libraries on java:

```
public static boolean loadBinaries(){
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    ArrayList<String> bins = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(os.indexOf("windows 7") >= 0){
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/libcurld.dll");
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/libfftw3f-3.dll");
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/libmad.dll");
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/libsamplerate.dll");
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/seven/main.dll");
    }
    else if(os.indexOf("windows xp") >= 0){
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/libcurld.dll");
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/libfftw3f-3.dll");
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/libmad.dll");
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/libsamplerate.dll");
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/xp/main.dll");
    }

    File f = null;
    for(String bin : bins){
        InputStream in = FileManager.class.getResourceAsStream(bin);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read = -1;
        try {
            String[] temp = bin.split("/");
            f = new File(TEMP_FOLDER + "/" + temp[temp.length-1]);
            File realF = new File(f.getAbsolutePath());
            if(realF.exists())
                f.delete();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(realF);

            while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            fos.close();
            in.close();

            System.load(f.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The executable jar works always perfectly on my machine, but not in others... I got the next errors from my tests:

```
(xp)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\temp\main.dll: Can't find dependent libraries at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)...

(seven)
C:\temp\main.dll: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect...
```

All the dlls are well written in the temp folder and, as I said, this works well in my computer. I had thought this could be because compiling in debug mode on VS. Unfortunately, turning it to release didn't change anything, unless returning smaller binaries.

What can this be? Is some configuration detail missing on visual studio?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `contains()` would be better instead of `indexOf()` and try with `c:\\temp\\mail.dll` .

Comment: I will change it by contains. That is the path returned by f.getAbsolutePath(). This simply don't work on some computers... I and suspect is in the ones don't have visual studio installed....

Comment: One more thing  I hope both are running on same arch. I mean 32 or 64 bit

Comment: yes, always tested on 32 bits

Comment: I hope you aren't passing -MD flag while compiling

Comment: hummm, that's could be something... I went to vs configuration solution and the command line is: ""/O2 /GL /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE" /D "_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /FD /EHsc /MD /Fo"Release\\" /Fd"Release\vc80.pdb" /W3 /nologo /c /Wp64 /Zi /TP /errorReport:prompt""
I see MD there... What's that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would copy all DLLs and then load them in two loops.

Second, from the error message it seems that there is yet another DLL that main.dll requires that is not present on the other machines.
It might be the C++ runtime libraries what often not installed in the version you need, which is why many games or other apps install those first.

Comment: where do I get these c++ libraries?

Comment: I used Dependency Walker to get sure about the main.dll dependencies. The missing are msvcp80.dll and msvcr80.dll. So I added and loaded them both. Now this return me the next box message: "Runtime error! Program C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe R6034 An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly. Please contact the application's support team for more information." I googled it and I think this is about the manifest, but didn't understood how to load it in java...

Comment: You probably have to register the DLLs in the system. Your best bet is to call the windows installer for the runtime libraries when your app is installing.

Comment: yeah, probably it is. I was hopeful to get a jar working without an installer. As this seems hard, I will follow your advice for now. Many thanks!

Comment: I would statically link Microsoft CRT, to avoid having to install those VC++ runtime redistributables.